# What is the best way to create reactjs slot pattern in webcomponent slot style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know there is popular approach to do "slot-like" pattern when developing with react, and it is **compound component pattern**. But i'm wondering what will happen if i try to mimmick the webcomponent slots pattern in react using custom react hooks like this?

The react slotted component:

```
export default function MyComponent({children}) => {
  const [slot] = useSlot(children);

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        {slot('header', <>Default component</>)}
      </header>
      <main>
        {slot()}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Component called by this:

```
<MyComponent>
  <h1 slot="title">My Component Title</h1>
  <p slot="description">Some descriptive text</p>
  <p>General content inside the module</p>
</MyComponent>
```

And this is my custom react hook:

```js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
const useSlots = (componentChildren) => {
    const slots = useMemo(() => {
        return React.Children.toArray(componentChildren).reduce((collector, child) => {
            let slotName = "general";
            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                slotName = child.props.slot || "general";
            }
            if (!collector[slotName]) {
                collector[slotName] = [];
            }
            collector[slotName].push(child);
            return collector;
        }, { general: [] });
    }, [componentChildren]);
    const slot = (name = "", defaultChildren = []) => {
        var _a;
        const children = !name ? slots.general : (_a = slots[name]) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : defaultChildren;
        return React.createElement(React.Fragment, {}, children);
    };
    const hasSlotFunction = (slot) => {
        return slots.hasOwnProperty(slot) && slots[slot].length > 0;
    };
    return [slot, hasSlotFunction];
};
export default useSlots;
```

Just wondering, would be any performance issues or anti pattern according to my approach?